# Cant seem to get the Pagination to work on my WooCommerce REST API application?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

What I got so far:

```
        [
            'wp_api' => true,
            'version' => 'wc/v3',
            'query_string_auth' => true //Force Basic Authentication as query string true and using under HTTPS
            
        ]
    );
        

try {
    $results = $woocommerce->get('orders?per_page=30');
    $result = count($results);
```

I tried to remove the query_string_auth but I dont get any data displayed.
FYI it works without the page=30 but then only displayed the first 10 items.

Any advice would help alot:

Comment: Can you share the the implementation of `get` method on that woocommerce class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get method accepts extra parameters.

```
$woocommerce->get($endpoint, $parameters = []);
```

Try like this

```
$woocommerce->get('orders', array('per_page' => 30));
```

More details can be seen [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nginx, check your Nginx configurations. Missing Nginx settings will ignore the GET method query parameters. So it might be the issue that your page or per_page parameter are simply being ignored.